# How to add a list item in yq version 4

Tags: yq

I am migrating a script from yq 3 to yq 4 and cannot get one thing working.

I have the following YAML and want to add a list item after targetNamespaces:

```
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1
kind: OperatorGroup
metadata:
  name: businessautomation-operator
  namespace: rhpam-user1
spec:
  targetNamespaces:
```

So the output should be:

```
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1
kind: OperatorGroup
metadata:
  name: businessautomation-operator
  namespace: rhpam-user1
spec:
  targetNamespaces:
  - rhpam-user1
```

This command worked for changing the namespace:

```
yq eval '.metadata.namespace = "rhpam-user1"' -i ./file.yaml
```

When I run the following I am getting an error:

```
yq eval '.spec.targetNamespaces[+] = "rhpam-user1"'  -i ./file.yaml 

Error: '' expects 2 args but there is 1
```

I can't seem to get the new yq command structure right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how I missed updating my question with the solution I found, but here it is...

Because there is only one array element I was able to get it working with this:

```
yq eval ".spec.targetNamespaces[0] = \"rhpam-user1\"" -i ./file.yaml
```

I did not test the solution suggested by @Inian.

Comment: If there is already a value in the list, this will _replace_ the previous first value in the list, rather than adding a new value to the end of the list.

Answer (score 5):

If the `targetNamespaces` is intended to be used as an array type, you need to enclose the target string in `[..]`, with `+=` as below (as tested on version 4.11.2)

```bash
yq '.spec.targetNamespaces += [ "rhpam-user1" ]' ./file.yaml
```

Use the `-i` flag for in-place substitution of the file, if the output appears as expected.

See [mikefarah/yq - Relative append](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/add#relative-append)

---

Note: Since [4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), yq's `eval/e` command is the default command and no longer needs to be specified.

Comment: @Skenvy - Thanks for the edit suggestion. I always avoid suggesting  `-i` flag in the command line when writing bash CLI answers. Because it poses a huge risk (depends on the tool), to overwrite the actual file, in case if someone reading it , incorrectly uses it. I made some edits on top of yours.